# Как назвать жителя, живущего в городе Гусь Хрустальный?

Tags: стилистика

А жителей и жительницу?

Answer (score 4):

Гусевец, гусевцы, гусевка.

Гусяк, гусяки, гусячка — разговорный варивнт.

Они себя называют ещё: гусяне (гусянин, гусянка); гусевчане (гусевчанин, гусевчанка).

Answer (score 0):

Русский орфографический словарь (и на сайте города это есть) гласит такое: гусевч'ане, -'ан, ед. ч. -'анин, -а (к Г'усь-Хруст'альный). Гусевчанку не упомянул.

Жаль, что никак не отражено в этом «гусевчане» красивое слово *хрустальный*.

Answer (score -1):

Гусевец (мужской род), гусевцы (мн.ч), гусевка (женский род). Себя называют **гусяне**.