# Жители Курска

Tags: нормы-языка

Как правильно называются жители Курска? Неужели, действительно неблагозвучным словом "куряне"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да.  Жители Курска: *куряне - курянин - курянка*.

При образовании названий жителей столько разных суффиксов используется, что какие-то закономерности трудно обнаружить. На форуме уже обсуждался подобный вопрос. Мне запомнилось слово  "минераловодка" - жительница Минеральных Вод.

Answer (score 0):

Куряне. И чего, извините, неблагозвучного, если эта форма используется почти тысячелетие?

[Минеральные воды](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/857/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B)
[Гусь-Хрустальный](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/809/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8C-%D1%85%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)
и т.д.